# Meteor Display Child Array Elements #each

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, handlebars.js

I'm trying to use Meteor's `#each` to display a JSON Object from Mongo with children. Say it looks like so:

```
{
data: {dorem: 'ipsum', dolor:'sit'},
amet: 'abcdefg'
}
```

Using `#each`, I currently have something like this

```
<template name="base">
    {{#each stuff}}
      {{> info}}
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

The `info` template looks something like this

```
<template name="info">
{{data.dorem}}
</template>
```

The method I'm using to generate `stuff` is

```
  Template.base.stuff = function () {

    return DBThatHasStuffInIt.find({sort:{ _id : -1 }});

  };
```

However, it is not working. Nothing is being displayed. The `base` template has been added, as well.

Does anybody know what the problem might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [find](http://docs.meteor.com/#find), requires a [selector](http://docs.meteor.com/#selectors):

```
return DBThatHasStuffInIt.find({}, {sort:{ _id : -1 }});
```

Comment: I'm sorry. the `{{/stuff}}` was just a typo I entered when bringing the code to SO. (I'm going to fix that in my question after I post this). I'll try your suggestion out. Thanks.

Comment: It works now. Thanks. And do you know perhaps how to order the collection by date? The above sort didn't seem to work...

Comment: To do that properly you should add a date field like `createdAt` to your documents when they get inserted.